# capture.capturePhoto() asks for permission and then gets exception in marshmallow

Tags: codenameone

I have a capture photo method in my app but when i click the button it ask for permission and after approving it gives following exception in marshmallow phone

```
Capture.capturePhoto(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
}
});
```

[image]

**Build hints**

[image]

error log:

```
02-19 11:53:29.299: W/ActivityManager(2674): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x4000003 cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Lenovo/IMG_20170219_115329.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{5b9e8c5 9196:com.lenovo.capitaleyenepal/u0a251} (pid=9196, uid=10251) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
02-19 11:53:29.299: W/System.err(9196): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x4000003 cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Lenovo/IMG_20170219_115329.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{5b9e8c5 9196:com.lenovo.capitaleyenepal/u0a251} (pid=9196, uid=10251) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
02-19 11:53:29.299: W/System.err(9196):     at com.lenovo.capitaleyenepal.Lenovo.lambda$showLogin$16(Lenovo.java:211)
02-19 11:53:29.299: W/System.err(9196):     at com.lenovo.capitaleyenepal.Lenovo.access$lambda$2(Lenovo.java)
02-19 11:53:29.299: W/System.err(9196):     at com.lenovo.capitaleyenepal.Lenovo$$Lambda$4.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace from DDMS?

Comment: It has been added above. plz have a look

Comment: So what's in Lenovo.java line 211?